# Login is not defined while trying Facebook Javascript SDk example?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am trying the Facebook login Javascript SDK example from the website.

http://hayageek.com/facebook-javascript-sdk/

the code is as below:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '113455642165175', // Set YOUR APP ID
      channelUrl : 'http://hayageek.com/examples/oauth/facebook/oauth-javascript/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) 
    {
     if (response.status === 'connected') 
    {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML +=  "<br>Connected to Facebook";
        //SUCCESS

    }    
    else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') 
    {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML +=  "<br>Failed to Connect";

        //FAILED
    } else 
    {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML +=  "<br>Logged Out";

        //UNKNOWN ERROR
    }
    }); 

    };

    function Login()
    {

        FB.login(function(response) {
           if (response.authResponse) 
           {
                getUserInfo();
            } else 
            {
             console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
         },{scope: 'email,user_photos,user_videos'});

    }

  function getUserInfo() {
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {

      var str="<b>Name</b> : "+response.name+"<br>";
          str +="<b>Link: </b>"+response.link+"<br>";
          str +="<b>Username:</b> "+response.username+"<br>";
          str +="<b>id: </b>"+response.id+"<br>";
          str +="<b>Email:</b> "+response.email+"<br>";
          str +="<input type='button' value='Get Photo' onclick='getPhoto();'/>";
          str +="<input type='button' value='Logout' onclick='Logout();'/>";
          document.getElementById("status").innerHTML=str;

    });
    }
    function getPhoto()
    {
      FB.api('/me/picture?type=normal', function(response) {

          var str="<br/><b>Pic</b> : <img src='"+response.data.url+"'/>";
          document.getElementById("status").innerHTML+=str;

    });

    }
    function Logout()
    {
        FB.logout(function(){document.location.reload();});
    }

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));

</script>
<div align="center">
<h2>Facebook OAuth Javascript Demo</h2>

<div id="status">
 Click on Below Image to start the demo: <br/>
<img src="http://hayageek.com/examples/oauth/facebook/oauth-javascript/LoginWithFacebook.png" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="Login()"/>
</div>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<div id="message">
Logs:<br/>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am seeing a "Login is not defined " error in javascript console when i click on the facebook login button. How do i get rid of this ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this happening because you are trying to access the Login button before the document is ready! try the following code.

```
$.document.ready(function(){
  //Place your code here!
});
```